# Upgrading to and setting up CAS 5.1.x with cas-server-webapp-tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, cas

I've been trying to change to a CAS 5.1.x Server from a 4.X Server for the past 3 days with various searches and research and next to no progress. Whenever I remove the dependency to cas-server-webapp-tomcat, the artifact deploys on the local tomcat apache server however it does not show anything except the standard Apache 404 error page. Here is the log for that case:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\dhogue\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_src-cas_2 "-Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat 70" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat 70\temp" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -cp "C:\Tomcat 70\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Tomcat 70\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
    [2017-09-27 01:11:17,832] Artifact src-cas:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Jun 30 2015 08:08:33 UTC
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         7.0.63.0
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            6.1
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          amd64
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\dhogue\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_src-cas_2
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Tomcat 70
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\dhogue\.IntelliJIdea2017.1\system\tomcat\Unnamed_src-cas_2
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat 70
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat 70\temp
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin;C:\Program Files\jscoverage-0.5.1;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.9/bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;.
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 929 ms
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-9090"]
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-9009"]
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 54 ms
    Connected to server
    [2017-09-27 01:11:19,924] Artifact src-cas:war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:22 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
    INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Tomcat 70\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Tomcat 70\webapps\manager
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:29 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Tomcat 70\webapps\manager has finished in 195 ms
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Sep 27, 2017 1:11:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
    [2017-09-27 01:11:30,468] Artifact src-cas:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
    [2017-09-27 01:11:30,468] Artifact src-cas:war: Deploy took 10,544 milliseconds
```

Whenever I try to run it with the cas-server-webapp-tomcat dependency no matter what I've tried, I've always ended up with an error as shown in the following log: [Error with cas-server-webapp-tomcat](https://gist.github.com/subhogue/b91e299e668d96fa96865f981451eb66)

Here is my current Pom file...excuse the mess: [cas.pom](https://gist.github.com/subhogue/a2919783054dacc6906fedde7fa9d4e5)

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA

Not sure what else would be needed, ask and I'll provide whatever you need to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things stand out to me:

1. cas-server-webapp-tomcat contains an embedded tomcat container. If you are using an external one, use cas-server-webapp.
2. It looks like your external tomcat is 7.x. You need at least Tomcat 8.

https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/installation/Configuring-Servlet-Container.html

Comment: thanks, but turns out I was deploying to root and therefore basically destroyed what should be in that folder, but using 7 was also a problem, so good answer.